# Extending Title Service in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, head

I am very new to TypeScript and I am still trying to figure out how to extend the TitleService.

Because of customizations involved in coining the Page Titles on my angular site, I have to extend the TitleService. Here's my code

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class PageTitleService extends Title {
constructor(public myOtherService: OtherService} {
super (null)}

public setPageTitle(customLabel: string) {
let title = this.myOtherService.getPageTitlebyLabel(customLabel)
this.setTitle(title) // this is wrong here. But how do I pass my consuming page component reference here?
}
}
```

And from my calling component

```
this.pageTitleService.setPageTitle('Home_Label');
```

Questions:

- The Title Service in Angular expects one constructor parameter which is: _doc: any. How do I construct my constructor in the extended class and what do I pass for `super(??)`, as _doc is not injectable?
- How do I call this `setpageTitle()` from my consuming component?

I have tried writing a getMethod() instead of set and set the title from my consuming page component. But it means that I have to import TitleService even from my consuming component and the whole point of extending the TitleService is lost

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But why do you want to extend the Title? Usually, you only call it on your page to dynamically change the title of your current page, so I don't see the usefulness of abstracting it further. Basically, calling it in your `ngOnInit` or page `constructor` would solve 100% of the cases.

Edit1: I believe this solution here can solve your doubts.

```js
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class PageTitleService {
    constructor(private myOtherService: any, private title: Title) {}
    
    setPageTitle(customLabel: string) {
        const title = this.myOtherService.getPageTitleByLabel(customLabel);
        this.title.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. But the problem is there is one part of the page title that  I have to append which is common across the site. It would be just duplicating that bit in like 100's of page components. In case that label changes, I have to go change it in 100's of components. That's why I want to abstract it out so that, I can append that bit in one place.

Comment: Could you show an example of code for this situation? Because the ideal way is to set a generic title correctly in your index.html, and for other pages where you want to change it, you manually add the title tag.

Comment: The above code is the example code and was my attempt to set the title dynamically. If it was a static hard coded title for every page, then I could have just injected the TitleService in my page components and just call the setTitle().  But I have logic and DB calls to be made to coin the Page titles before setting it. I can't use router based titles either, as everything is dynamic in our site.

Comment: So, instead of extending the Title in this case, couldn't you simply set it in the constructor's initialization? You wouldn't need to extend it; instead, you could implement it within the class.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, there is one bit in the page title that I append which is common across all pages and which is static. I want that common static bit outside of these component classes, because in case it changes, I don't want to go and change 100's of page component classes.

Comment: import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";

export class PageTitleService {
  constructor(private myOtherService: any, private title: Title) {}

  setPageTitle(customLabel: string) {
    const title = this.myOtherService.getPageTitleByLabel(customLabel);

    this.title.setTitle(title);
  }
}

Wouldn't this solve your problem?

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, as I thought initially, I could extend/override the Title service methods instead of doing this.   Also, I thought you were referring to constructors in the individual components above and that's why I kept saying there is a static bit that I don't want to repeat. My apologies, as I am still new to TypeScript. Thanks though! This is the exact code I ended up writing and this is what I meant when I wrote 'wrapper' around the Title Service.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your doubt/problem, I'll edit my answer to the one that helped you there if possible it would help if you could vote for it too. In the end we managed to conclude this doubt hehe

Answer (score 0):

Man! I just realized Angular has marked the Title class as 'Final'. I cannot extend it. I wasted one hour trying to figure out how to extend it. I will write a wrapper service around the TitleService, instead of extending it. This is the eventual code:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyOtherService } from '../other-service/my-other.service'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
}) 

export class PageTitleService { 

  constructor(public myOtherService: MyOtherService,

     private titleService: Title) {
  } 

  public setPageTitle(mainLabel: string) {

    let pageTitle = '';
    let subTitle = this.myOtherService.get('STATIC_LABEL); 

    if (mainLabel == '')
      title = subTitle;
    else
      title = this.myOtherService.get(mainLabel) + " - " + subTitle; 

    this.titleService.setTitle(title);   

  }

}
```

and the call to this from the individual page components is simply this ( where pageTitleService in the code below, is the injected parameter of the above service):

```
ngOnInit(): void 
{    
    this.pageTitleService.setPageTitle('PAGE_LABEL'); // OR PASS ''       
}
```

Comment: if you extend your question please edit your question and extend it,,,

Comment: @JoSSte, I didn't get it:-).

Comment: this "answer" read more like a comment...